# How to carry honey jars and prevent losses?

Tags: air-travel, luggage, tips-and-tricks

I am flying soon and I will have a honey jar in my checked baggage.

Since it is no longer brand new (I already used part of it), it is no longer hermetically closed, so I am quite afraid it will spill on the rest of the things I will be carrying.

Is there any trick on how to pack/protect such jars?

I was planning to use some tight plastic bag, then some paper around it (to absorbe possible spills) and finally another bag.

Comment: Pour it out of the jar into a baggie, freeze it, put the baggie into an insulated bag, seal with masking tape.

Comment: How was it closed originally? Does it have a threaded cap?

Comment: @GayotFow sounds awfully messy, then you'd have to thaw it and pour it somewhere else, I can imagine it'll stick everywhere and you'll lose a lot of it in the process

Comment: @GayotFow apparently it is not a good idea. I have read that freezing honey makes it lose part of its properties, since it decrystallizes it. Still, this may also happen in the cabin of the plane.

Comment: Put the jar into a zip-lock bag and try to expunge as much air from the bag as possible when closing it.  The bag is hermetically sealed - so any spillage would be contained.  If you want to be doubly-sure, put that zip-lock bag into another zip-lock bag and, again, seal expunging the air. I've transported honey this way many times, as well as home made jams.

Comment: Keep in mind that if your jar is not sealed or marked - it may not be allowed through customs.  Check with the country you are traveling to - otherwise securing it maybe a moot point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I regularly travelled with liquid and semi liquid products and the best way to avoid a big problem is to put it in a jar (even glass should be ok) with a threaded cap. Then protect it in a box specifically designed for jars. You have a lot of examples there :
[Sample protection box for jars](https://www.google.fr/search?q=box%20for%20jars&biw=1280&bih=781&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjO_fWxmM_KAhXLuhoKHRtyCtAQ_AUIBigB)